# CMake: Generate single header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently in the process of writing a Utility Library that will ship with a pre-compiled DLL file and the header files of the library. As of now, there are a whole bunch of header files, but I would like to compile all of them into a single header file (somewhat like pre-processing only the `#include` directives).

I was wondering, if and how such a generation would be possible using CMake.

Sincerely,
Lehks

Comment: With that said, the only project I can think of currently with something like this is the [Catch test framework](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2). Perhaps you can look at how they do it?

Answer (score 2):

*These tools are not specific to CMake, but can be invoked inside CMake.*

I recently collected together some links to create a single-header release for [ApprovalTests.cpp](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp).

I initially recorded them in a comment on [an issue in podsiadly/ImageApprovals](https://github.com/p-podsiadly/ImageApprovals/issues/1#issuecomment-598113213): this answer is to make that info easier to share.

## C++ - Single-header Release Scripts

Options:

- Some of these tools only pull together header files, which is fine if your master source code is header-only.
- Others also have a way to pull in .cpp files, either adding `inline` to the output, or putting all the code from .cpp files into one location in the output, this is compiled only once.

  - This is how Catch2's `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` works, for example.

### Claiming to be general

- [quom](https://github.com/Viatorus/quom)

  - Uses Python
  - Does not mention adding `inline`
- [Heady](https://github.com/JamesBoer/Heady)

  - C++ program
  - Does specifically explain pulling in `.cpp` files
  - Does acknowledge need to add `inline` to some functions from .cpp: has a (customisable) convention for putting `inline_t` in your source code, for where `inline` should be included in the generated header
- [Corrade Acme](https://doc.magnum.graphics/corrade/acme.html)

  - Uses Python
  - You create a kind of template file that contains `#include` lines, and various template mark-up, Pragmas and so-on
  - Does not mention pulling in `.cpp` files?
  - Does not mention adding `inline`

### Library Specific

- [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/)

  - [scripts/generateSingleHeader.py](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/scripts/generateSingleHeader.py)
  - I think it reads this and expands headers: [include/catch.hpp](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/include/catch.hpp)
  - Then looks for this text `// ~*~* CATCH_CPP_STITCH_PLACE *~*~` - which it finds in [include/internal/catch_impl.hpp](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/include/internal/catch_impl.hpp), and pastes all .cpp files in, in alphabetical order
- [ImageApprovals](https://github.com/p-podsiadly/ImageApprovals)

  - [single_header.py](https://github.com/p-podsiadly/ImageApprovals/blob/master/scripts/single_header.py)
  - Has tests: [single_header_test.py](https://github.com/p-podsiadly/ImageApprovals/blob/master/scripts/single_header_test.py)
  - Should be reusable
  - The script:

    - goes over all headers/sources
    - removes include guards and relative `#include`s (in `preprocess_file`)
    - sorts files topologically (if `a.hpp` includes `b.hpp` then `b.hpp` will be processed first, `SingleHeaderGen.generate`)
    - and finally merges everything into a single header, with public headers first and implementation files inside `#ifdef/#endif`.
    - code from .cpp files will be compiled only once, when `ImageApprovals_IMPLEMENT` is defined
- [jfalcou/spy](https://github.com/jfalcou/spy)

  - [embed.py](https://github.com/jfalcou/spy/blob/develop/script/embed.py)
  - Removes comments
  - Removes extra include guards
  - Doesn't deal with `.cpp` files
- [ApprovalTests.cpp](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp)

  - Implemented in [build/scripts/](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp/blob/master/build/scripts/)
  - Doesn't deal with `.cpp` files
  - Relevant scripts:
  - [code_generation.py](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp/blob/master/build/scripts/code_generation.py)
  - [single_header_file.py](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp/blob/master/build/scripts/single_header_file.py)
  - [embed.py](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.cpp/blob/master/build/scripts/embed.py)

    - This is a modified version of the jfalcou/spy script above.
    - Retains comments
    - Has option to discard particular patterns of lines ("discardables")
    - Includes names of original files in comments