# How to generate a single file with all the code inline, without #include?

Tags: c++

Given a C++ library (a folder that contains all the `.h` and `.cpp` files), how to generate a single `.cpp` file that contains all of the code (inline) without using the `#include` directive?

Comment: Please consider posting this type of question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , but first read their rules. A possible dupe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887018/cmake-generate-single-header-file

Comment: C++ compilers do not have the capability of handling this for you, so you will have to use external tools to preprocess and merge your source files as needed.

Comment: Kind of sounds like they just want `g++ -E`.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `g++ -E folder/*.cpp > output.cpp` do the trick?  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: I don't think there is a general solution. You can't just concatenate all your translation units together, you have to ensure names with internal linkage are unique

Comment: @G.M. your suggestion do the trick! thanks but i need to do ti recursevelly, becase the file that has been included in the first levele include itself other file, `g++ -E *.cpp > result.cpp` is there a way to make this command recursive?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your last comment.  You should create a new question providing all of the relevant details.  Please also state *why* you are trying to do this -- it may be that there is a better way of achieving what you want.